# Viewstate move session generate an error as 'The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted. '

Tags: asp.net

I have created web page with rad grid. within that i provide facility to filtering ,shorting, Grouping and paging . because of performance issue i have tried to move viewsatate into session.
there i have set enable viewsate false in webpage  and added bellow code into page.

```
    protected override object LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium()
    {
        return Session["ViewState-" + Request.Url.AbsolutePath];

    }
    protected override void SavePageStateToPersistenceMedium(object state)
    {
        Session["ViewState-" + Request.Url.AbsolutePath] = state;

        ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField("__VIEWSTATE", "");
    }
```

but when i do some thing on rad grid it will generate bellow error

The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ASP.NET 2.0 or higher, Microsoft has built-in functionality for ViewState in Session. You should use it for maximum compatibility.

Just put this in your .CS file

```
protected override PageStatePersister PageStatePersister
{
  get
  {                
     return new System.Web.UI.SessionPageStatePersister(this);
  }
}
```

Link at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/system.web.ui.sessionpagestatepersister.aspx

Comment: Thank you MikeLim , I removed  EnableViewState="false" and put your code into my .cs page.
it's fixed my error but its not effect to performance of the page.
Still page size is very huge.